# How Do I Prevent Buttons From Stacking on Mobile?

Tags: css, button, mobile, format

Site URL: https://anthonysavarese.com/my-photos/

[image of stacking buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pumAg.png)

Hi, how I can prevent the buttons in the link above from stacking on mobile? I'd like to have them center-aligned and on the same row.

I tried adding different pieces of CSS code I found online and none of them have solved it. I also tried adjusting the HTML tag from div to the other options and haven't had any luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`display: flex` is your best bet.
But you could also use `display grid` as an option. Below is a snippet using display flex.

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
  .gutentor-element-button-group-wrap { 
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     justify-content: center;
     margin-bottom:30px;
  }
}
```

Adjust the `768px` breakpoint to when you'd like the mobile view to trigger.

And the `margin-bottom:30px` is optional.
I added it to give you some space at the bottom.

If you want to learn more on display flex, here is a deeper dive into its logic. **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout**

Comment: Thank you!! I appreciate the info as well :)